# Extract the string after title in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

html result is `<div class="font-160 line-110" data-container=".snippet container" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-template='&lt;div class="tooltip infowin-tooltip" role="tooltip"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow-inner"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-inner" style="text-align: left"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' data-toggle="tooltip" title="XIAMEN [CN]">`

How do I pull out `"XIAMEN [CN]"` right after `title`. I tried `find_all('title')` but that does not return a match. Nor can I call any from of `siblings` to traverse my way down the result. I couldn't even get `find(text='XIAMEN [CN]')` to return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myHTML = 'what you posted above'
soup = BeautifulSoup(myHTML, "html5lib")
title = soup.find('div')['title']
```

We're just searching for `<div>` tags here, you'll probably want to be more specific in vivo.

Comment: I used `soup = BeautifulSoup(myHTML, "html.parser")`before, why does `html5lib` work here?

Comment: BeautifulSoup and python both ship with a couple of parsers, and there are 3rd party packages as well. Some are faster, some more lenient, and rarely, some fail where others succeed. 99% of the time, there's no difference, I just use the one I'm most used to. They're all covered here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Answer (score 1):

You should use the class or some attribute to select the div, calling `find("div")` would select the first div on the page,  also *title* is an attribute not a tag so you need to access the *title attribute* once you locate the tag. A few of examples of how to be specific and extract the *attribute*:

```
html = """<div class="font-160 line-110" data-container=".snippet container" data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-template='&lt;div class="tooltip infowin-tooltip" role="tooltip"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow"&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-arrow-inner"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class="tooltip-inner" style="text-align: left"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' data-toggle="tooltip" title="XIAMEN [CN]">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# use the css classes
print(soup.find("div", class_="font-160 line-110")["title"])

# use an attribute value
print(soup.find("div", {"data-container": ".snippet container"})["title"])
```

If there is only one div with an attribute, look for the div setting *title=True*:

```
soup.find("div", title=True)
```

You can also combine the steps, i.e the class and one or more attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly safer way than the other answer

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myHTML = 'what you posted above'
soup = BeautifulSoup(myHTML, "html5lib")
div = soup.find('div')
title = div.get('title', '')  # safe way to check for the title, incase the div doesn't contain it
```